# How to only include the styling of one angular material component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to use only a single Angular material component. However, the only example for theming/styling I can find, is with

```
@include mat.all-component-themes($theme);
```

Which includes styling of all the material components.
But I only want the styling for the Snackbar component. Where can I find information on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is described in the [theming guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#applying-a-theme-to-components). First, you need to load the core theme, then you can load the theme(s) of individual component(s). In your case it would be:

```scss
@include mat.core-theme($theme);
@include mat.snack-bar-theme($theme);
```